# How to pass correctly latin chars like "ś" in jmeter login post request

Tags: jmeter, iso-8859-2

When I wish to login as "pieraś", the page detects login "pieraĹ"

I tried selecting "URL ENCODE", changing jmeter.property csvdataset.file.encoding_list to "ISO 8859-2" only as well ass UTF-8 only.

[JMETER request picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VspNG.png)

How to make it work right?

Answer (score 0):

In the HTTP request field "Content Encoding:" manually enter value "ISO-8859-2".
It works against jmeter.property "sampleresult.default.encoding"

Comment: Did Content Encoding was the solution to your issue? I asked about it previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179373/jmeter-http-requests-content-encoding-field-has-no-effect

Comment: Yes, when I add a value for "Content Encoding" in a HTTP Request sampler it works for me (JMETER 5.1.1). I'm no sure if the case you mentioned with gzip isn't related to mime-type set in Header Manager as you want to send a file. (Please note that I am new to www testing and Jmeter).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use "pieraś" in jmeter, looks like JMeter is passing and processing this value properly. Some sample snap given below:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In your example, you edit "BODY DATA" while my case is about "PARAMETERS"